# shorten onclick code for several elements - javascript

Tags: javascript

hi there i have 60 image tags.. clicking on each tag displays a different text in a textbox.. soo i was wondering instead of typing `javascript` code in each image tag is there any way to do this using a single `javascript` function... and putting that function in the `onclick=""` event of every image tag.. hope i made myself clear... any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance.. :) oh and below are all the 60 image tags...

```
    <img src='smileys/birthday.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
<img src='smileys/blue.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/blush.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/boo.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/book.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/busted.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/goodnight.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/newhere.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/nicethread.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/nospamhere.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/offtopic.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-ashamed004.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-confused001.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-confused013.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-dance012.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-dance019.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-excited001.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-fart004.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-fart005.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-finger005.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-gen013.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-gen041.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-gen055.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
     <img src='smileys/smiley-gen073.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-happy011.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-happy020.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-happy120.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-hug001.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-hug004.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-hug005.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-hug006.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-hug014.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-hug015.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-laughing001.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-laughing002.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love001.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love007.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love010.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love018.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love019.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
     <img src='smileys/smiley-love022.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love025.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love027.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-love028.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-taunt002.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-taunt014.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/welcome.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
     <img src='smileys/smiley-sad008.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/wtf.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />  
     <img src='smileys/smiley-confused002.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-angelic002.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-cool02.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-devil03.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-happy112.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-happy119.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-sad056.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/smiley-sad007.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" /> 
      <img src='smileys/smiley-confused005.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
      <img src='smileys/cheekkiss.gif' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
     <img src='smileys/toj.png' style="height:22px;margin:3px;" />
```

Comment: You've tagged `jquery` but I see no jquery. Please make an attempt rather than simply asking someone to write code for you.

Comment: i'm sorry.. but i have no idea where to start...

Comment: http://www.jquery.com http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+onclick&oq=jquery+onclick&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2j0l2.3002j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the text you're displaying in that textbox as a data attribute:

```
<img src='smileys/birthday.gif' data-text="Happy birthday" style="..." />
```

and do

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#textbox').text( $(this).data('text') );  // or val() if it's an input
});
```

If you have other images that this shouldn't apply to, use a class as a selector instead.

Comment: by class do u mean this...  
`$('class').on('click', function() {
    $('#textbox').text( $(this).data('text') );  // or val() if it's an input
});`

Comment: Yes, but `$('.images')` added to the element as `<img class="images" />`